# How to customize an iOS TextView with pickTagInput? Just Like TagPicker By JavaScript

Tags: ios, tags, uitextview, uipickerview, uiresponder

iOS Dev:

`UITextView`(/`UITextField`) which its inputView is Kind Of `UIPickerView` Class,

So I can select multiple cities.

While the Tags(labels), could be clicked removed Only the right part of it where there is a fork image(button).

Like the picture: 
[image]

PS:

I tried to put buttons on `UITextField`, with city(data) selected By `UIPickerView` (inputView).

I want to click the button, the button `removedFromSuperView`. The Button's SEL doesn't work.

The result is that `UITextField` become theFirstResponder.

I think UIRespond Chain matters.

PPS:

Some like `YYText + UIPickView.`

Good, [looks like the demo](http://howardjing.github.io/angularjs-tagpicker/)  angularjs-tagpicker.

Just Like TagPicker by JavaScript

PPPS: [Github Code](https://github.com/dengV/textViewInputedByUIPickerViewDemoPlu)

Comment: How do you position the tags? Are you using a [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html)?

Comment: No.  I know UICollectionView is strong.  I use [AOTag](https://github.com/Appsido/AOTag),  and replace the content UITextField(View) by a content UIView(added Gesture with event that can  add tag view on it ).

Comment: AOTag is closed source... there is nothing we can do to help.

Comment: I take the code, rewrite it to adapt my project.  It works well. To make it better, maybe  UICollectionViewFlowLayout.  Since AOTag is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shift the way of thinking.

Not to take the UITextField/UITextView as the tags container instead by a UIView.
Then OK.